# Error - Declaration is incompatible with during function implementation

Tags: c++, azerothcore

I'm trying to implement a function from another project and during the porting I'm getting the error above on the title on the following piece.

I've got a file with the declaration of the function that goes along the lines.

**ObjectMgr.h**

```
class ObjectMgr
{
    friend class PlayerDumpReader;

private:
    ObjectMgr();
    ~ObjectMgr();

    std::unique_ptr<PlayerInfo> _playerInfo[MAX_RACES][MAX_CLASSES];

public:
(...)
    PlayerInfo const* GetPlayerInfo(uint32 race, uint32 class_) const;
(...)
```

**ObjectMgr.cpp**

```
/* Error on GetPlayerInfo
 * E0147    declaration is incompatible with "const PlayerInfo *ObjectMgr::GetPlayerInfo(uint32 
 * race, uint32 class_) const" (declared at line 756 of "D:\_AZEROTHCORE\AZEROTHCORE-
 * WOTLK\SRC\SERVER\GAME\GLOBALS\ObjectMgr.h")  game    D:\_azerothcore\azerothcore- 
 * wotlk\src\server\game\Globals\ObjectMgr.cpp  9163    
 */
PlayerInfo const* ObjectMgr::GetPlayerInfo(uint32 race, uint32 class_) const
{
    if (race >= MAX_RACES)
        return nullptr;
    if (class_ >= MAX_CLASSES)
        return nullptr;
    auto const& info = ObjectMgr::_playerInfo[race][class_];
    if (!info)
        return nullptr;
    return info->get();
}
```

It's really confusing to me because I do have the header file imported and the names and types are the exact same. Could It be because I have another error on
`info->get()` ?

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Replacing `info->get()` by `info.get()` and filling missing parts, compile fine [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/879bb7904a979e35).

Comment: This project is huge but I'll try to do it. I did replace the Info but I'm getting another error which is `return value does not match the function type`. I'm looking at the other project where I'm importing from and the code looks the exact same...

Answer (score 0):

It was indeed a return type issue. Solved by changing the type to:

```
PlayerInfo* _playerInfo[MAX_RACES][MAX_CLASSES];
```

and

```
PlayerInfo* info = _playerInfo[race][class_];
```